# Adobe edge play animation 3 times then stop on a specific frame

Tags: javascript, adobe, adobe-edge

I have an animation created in Edge that I need to play 3 times and then stop on a specific frame.
I'm new to javascript and I think I need to use a variable and if/else statement, but am unsure what to use and how to write it. Any help would be much appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 4):

Reluctantly I reply, really you need to provide some code to show your attempts. However, as this is a useful starter question I'll attempt an answer.

First thing you'll need is a global scoped variable to store the loop counter. Add something like this to your Stage.compositionComplete function.

```
// Add a numLoops variable to global storage
sym.setVariable("numLoops", 0);
```

Next at the end of your animation via the Timelines actions, create an event to capture that variable, increment, and replay the animation if applicable like so:

```
// capture numLoops variable and increment the counter
var numLoopsHolder = sym.getVariable("numLoops");
numLoopsHolder = numLoopsHolder + 1;

// set new numLoops variable back to global storage
sym.setVariable("numLoops", numLoopsHolder);

if (numLoopsHolder <= 2) {
    // replay scene until 3 iterations are complete
    sym.play(0);
}
```

This will get it looping 3 times, but you still need to add a stop check at the desired timeline location via:

```
// capture numLoops variable to check for 3 loops (ie. 0, 1, 2 = 3 loops)
var numLoopsHolder = sym.getVariable("numLoops");

if (numLoopsHolder >= 2) {
    // we've completed 3 loops now stop here
    sym.stop();
}
```

Here's a screenshot of the timeline for action event references.
[image]

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your help and sorry for not posting any code, I'll remember to do that next time, I'm new here.

I tried this and it works, but I need it to play up to the frame it needs to stop at. 

here's a link to the live demo:
http://www.noirworldwide.com/puzzletest/puzzlebanner.html

I need the animation to stop on the 3rd frame, the one that says "We deliver, short and simple"

Comment: Good day, indeed the above code does include code to do just that. Of course this is assuming a fairly basic setup (the cube in the screenshot). If this approach isn't working in your use case perhaps you could put up the code your trying and we can sort through it. Having checked the link it seems to be working for me?

Comment: Hi, Thanks for all your help! I used the code you provided above and it works. It does everything I need it to except one thing. After the animation has loped 3 times I need it to play until the 3rd frame, right now what it is doing is after looping 3 times it goes straight to the 3rd frame skipping over the animation. Could you help me with this?

Comment: Here's a screengrab of the code in the program over the timeline. http://www.noirworldwide.com/puzzletest/screengrab.jpg

Comment: Indeed, in your screenshot right where the red line is drop a timeline action there by using the {o} icon on the Actions line. Then drop the last bit of code there. Right now you have the loop action and custom stop frame on the last frame of the animation, thus jumping to the label. You want that code out of there, let the animation start the last time and get caught on the end frame where the red line is.